# How to enable Dev Options or Debugging Mode on Android with black screen and fresh resetted device

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, usb-debugging

I have Samsung Galaxy A50. I just resetted it just before the device fell from my hand. Now, I just want to access my device with SCRCPY. But the problem is I cannot access the usb debugging either the internal storage. So Android basically have setup wizard at first device got resetted and I cant skip this.

I have tried to take several screenshot. Expecting this one to appear inscreenshot folder from Internal Storage. But still it wont appear unless I already finished the setup wizard

Is there any solution?